# Grails Currencies Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I wanted to try Grails-Currencies plugin. I found the source on GitHub https://github.com/ricardojmendez/grails-currencies. So, I downloaded the zip from there, renamed the zip according to the description in plugin.xml and ran the command:

grails install-plugin absolute path to the zip file. ( The Grails documentation refers to an online link which is an older version. So, preferred this method. )

I got a success message that the plugin is installed. But, I don't see any of the plugin files in my current project. None of the source files are installed into my project. I then understood that plugins actually just modify the application.properties file and registers the plugin there but maintains all the plugin related files in $HOME/.grails. Now my questions are:

1. Where do I find this $HOME/.grails folder ( am asking just out of curiosity as I didn't find any in Grails installation home folder.
2. How do I use or access the currency plugin files or it's features in my Grails application? Do I copy the plugin files ( once you help me find them ) into my current project and then work on them? If so, I can as well copy them from the GitHub zip I downloaded. So, basically how do I go about it while making sure I leverage Grails Currency plugin and keep my existing project intact.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not GRAILS_HOME, but it's your home folder. Your home folder location is dependent on the OS you use. For example In linux it will be /home/username. On macos it will be located /Users/username.
2. After you have installed the plugin and grails have added it to the application.properties file, you are ready to use it. Just start using plugin's features, the plugin will be picked up by grails automatically.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on that? What is HOME folder? An also I tried with adding the currencies dependency. Can you explain more on yoir second point as well?

Comment: Thank you Funtik. I found the zip in my userfolder/.grails thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Funtik, my reputation was still 14 yesterday when I tried. So couldn't accept it as minimum needed is 15. Now I can it seems.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the way you installed the plugin is not recommended. You should simply add this to your BuildConfig.groovy under plugins:

```
compile ":currencies:1.3.2"
```

This will set up the plugin to be installed. To get the files immediately, run this:

```
grails refresh-dependencies
```

Comment: Well I did try with the dependency in BuildConfig too. It does the same and I got Success message in both cases. But I don't see any of the source files from the plugin in my project. Do they go anywhere else? How do I use them in my current project. Could you please help me by elaborating a bit more?

Comment: Or do you mean if I do refresh-dependecies it will copy the plugin files to my project? Becoz I didn't try refreshing. I will try that but was wondering if it will copy the files !!

Comment: James, I tried refresh-dependencies, which now seems to be changed to RefreshDependencies and I got a success message "Dependencies Refreshed". But I don't see any of the pluging related files in my project. I am not sure if I can be more clear on my question or if I am missing any basic concepts about plugins.

Comment: Thank you James for your time. I found the zip in <userfolder>/.grails.